# why float and double does not identify 0 in decimal places

Tags: c++, decimal

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

double var = 1.0;
cout << var << endl;


system("pause");
return 0;
```

output:

```
1   
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

`float` and `double` only represent the **values** of numbers. “1” and “1.0” are both numerals for the same number, so 1 is the correct value of the `var` you set to 1.0. `float` and `double` do not represent the original numerals used to set their values, nor do they represent how much accuracy (relative to some ideal mathematical value) is present. The “1” you see as output is a result of default formatting. Other formatting options are available, but you must specify them yourself.